# Do "lspci" and "lshw" commands always show graphics driver?

Tags: drivers, xorg, display, xubuntu, lshw

I recently acquired an older motherboard with SiS built-in graphics and installed Xubuntu on it. I wanted to challenge myself and see if I could figure out how to install a graphics driver for SiS. After a bit of work, I believe I actually managed to do just that by using [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SiS) guide with a few tweaks. I have come to the conclusion that I was successful because originally, */var/log/Xorg.0.log* was showing an error saying that the "sis" module I was trying to use failed to load. With a final tweak, */var/log/Xorg.0.log* was showing the "sis" module being successfully loaded, and the resolution of the display also increased. However, when I checked the output of `lspci -v` and `lshw -c video`, there was no reference to the sis driver. Do these commands always show the graphics driver being used? Am I wrong in thinking that I did this successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lspci` and `lshw` only show driver information for hardware handled by a kernel driver. In your case, the graphics hardware is managed by a X.org driver, not a kernel driver, so the driver doesn’t show up in the output of `lspci` or `lshw`.

The fact that your screen resolution increased is a strong indicator that you succeeded, as is the successful loading of the `sis` module traced in the X.org server logs.